# Python Multiline String: How to get the cut based on search value

Tags: python, string, search

I have huge text string like the following in Python 3 Anaconda running Spyder3:

```
search="germany"

text = "germany's gabriel denies report he is eyeing finmin post
berlin (reuters) - german foreign minister sigmar gabriel on saturday denied 
a report that said the social democrat, whose party has agreed to enter 
talks with chancellor angela merkel's conservatives on forming a coalition, 
was eyeing the post of finance minister.


13.5 hours ago
— reuters





iit-kharagpur gets over 1,000 placement offers in eight days
quantiphi analytics emerged as the largest recruiter of the season till date 
offering 34 jobs, followed by intel at 33
13.5 hours ago
— business standard"
```

I am able to search inside the text using the following condition:

```
if search in text:
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

But what I really need is to get all the news text related to let us say "Germany" starting from "germany's gabriel denies report ..." right upto "the post of finance minister" in case germany is found inside text.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this feat?
A Thousand thanks in advance for all your answers.

Comment: Is it correct to restate this as "I need to get each paragraph where `Germany` appears in the text"? If so, maybe you can just split your string by `"\n\n"` and get the elements that match? Or the regex-based answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ez but you should read about regex(regular expressions) cause i don't know the whole data structure:

```
import re
search = input("Insert keyword")
text ="............."
if re.search(r'%s(.*?)\n\n'%(search),text,re.DOTALL) == None:
    print("Sorry did't found")
else:
    news = re.search(r'%s(.*?)\n\n'%(search),text,re.DOTALL).group()
    print(news)
```

Comment: let me try please.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching for `"Germany"`, search for `"German"` instead, to cover both cases. You may also need to convert everything to lowercase/uppercase to search sub strings of any case.

You can first get all of the substring locations with [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re

search="German"

text = """germany's gabriel denies report he is eyeing finmin postberlin 
(reuters) - german foreign minister sigmar gabriel on saturday denied 
a report that said the social democrat, whose party has agreed to enter 
talks with chancellor angela merkel's conservatives on forming a coalition, 
was eyeing the post of finance minister."""

# converted to lowercase to making searching easier
sub_locs = [s.start() for s in re.finditer(search.lower(), text.lower())]
print(sub_locs)
```

Which will give:

```
[0, 75]
```

Then you can slice and add sub strings in `text` with respect to the indices from `sub_locs`:

```
substrings = []
for start, end in zip(sub_locs[:-1], sub_locs[1:]):
    substrings.append(text[start:end])

# Get last substring
substrings.append(text[end:])

print("GERMAN SUBSTRINGS:")
for i, substr in enumerate(substrings):
    print("{0} -> {1}\n".format(i + 1, substr))
```

Which outputs:

```
GERMAN SUBSTRINGS
1 -> germany's gabriel denies report he is eyeing finmin postberlin (reuters) - 

2 -> german foreign minister sigmar gabriel on saturday denied 
a report that said the social democrat, whose party has agreed to enter 
talks with chancellor angela merkel's conservatives on forming a coalition, 
was eyeing the post of finance minister.
```